# -webkit-border-radius and -webkit-border-image at the same time. Does it work?

Tags: css, webkit

Is it possible to round the corners of elements with webkit background gradients? The below code seems to ignore the rounded corners.

```
#mydiv {
        border-width: 10px;
        width: 75px;
        height: 75px;
        margin: 0px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-border-image: 
            -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,
             color-stop(0%,#f6f5f8),
             color-stop(25%,#7e7699),
             color-stop(50%,#120634),
             color-stop(75%,#7e7699),
             color-stop(100%,#f5f5f8)) 10;

}
```

Comment: You're setting two border properties and no background properties. This is probably where you're tripping up.

Answer (score 0):

Try using background-image instead of border-image. For example:

```
.mydiv {
        width: 75px;
        height: 75px;
        margin: 0px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-image:
        -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
                color-stop(0%,#f6f5f8),
                color-stop(25%,#7e7699),
                color-stop(50%,#120634),
                color-stop(75%,#7e7699),
                color-stop(100%,#f5f5f8));
}
```

Comment: What for? That sets the background, not the border.